# WPF Binding Converter for Collection

Tags: wpf, collections, binding, typeconverter

I have a WPF treeview used to display a file structure. Each treeitem has a collection of enums to determine custom status' of the item. I.E. `ObservableCollection<enumType> statusCollection;`

I have several ellipses that are displayed when a treeitem has one of these status... something like this:

```
<Ellipse Margin="3,0" Visibility="{Binding StatusCollection, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" Width="12" Height="12" Fill="Red" />
```

Is there a way I can use the same Converter for multiple ellipses to check for a specific status... via an argument perhaps? Right now in the Converter, i loop through the collection looking for the specific enum... doing this, I would have to create a new Converter for each enum created, which is not ideal.

Better yet, how would I go about dynamically creating Ellipses for each status  in a treeviewitem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a `ConverterParameter` to the `Binding`:

```
Visibility="{Binding StatusCollection,
      Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter},
      ConverterParameter={x:Static local:MyEnumType.EnumValue}}"
```

This will then be passed into your `IValueConverter` as the `parameter` (third parameter) in

```
Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
```

You can then use the parameter within your converter however you need.